# How to configure Simplenote client to use external storage?

Tags: applications, external-sd

I've just installed the official [Simplenote client](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.automattic.simplenote) on my Samsung Galaxy S3 mini (Android 4.2.2). I don't have a lot of space on the "on board" storage, so want to ensure that Simplenote uses the external SD card.

I cannot find any settings for file storage, however, and I failed to find its files poking around with a file manager.

**Question** How can I ensure Simplenote is using the external SD card for storing its data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplenote files are hidden in Android. No way to access or export beyond the syncing provided by the app.